# JavaScript integer overflow

Tags: javascript, math, overflow

The following code

```
console.log(Math.pow(2, 53)); 
console.log(Math.pow(2, 53) + 1);
```

produces exactly same output for both calculations:

```
9007199254740992
```

Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-to

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The result you see occurs because `Math.Pow()` is working with floating point numbers, and when you reach the 16th decimal digit, you can't necessarily add one to the least significant decimal digit of the value and expect the result to change.

There are typically, in a 64-bit (8-byte) [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) floating-point binary value, 53 bits for the mantissa (including the implied 1-bit).  Your calculation `Math.Pow(2, 53)` requires 54 bits in the mantissa to be guaranteed of a change.  If you add 2, you should see the change.

Answer (score -3):

All Javascript numbers are double.

Comment: No. All numbers in JavaScript are 64-bit floating point numbers.